# In listing of data form is rendered when any input edited?

Tags: laravel-livewire, alpine.js

with livewire 1.3 / alpinejs 2.x.x I make listing of data with filter text
and selection inputs and clicking on “Search” button I need to run search when
“Search” button is clicked.
But search is run when text/selection input lose focus without clicking on “Search” button.
I see it by form's  wire:loading block and 1 line in log file, which I trigger in render method
That is not what I need : I need to run render method only clicking on “Search” button.
I tried to use alpinejs, but failed...
In  component app/Http/Livewire/Admin/AppNews.php I have:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Admin;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Livewire\Component;
use App\News;
use Livewire\WithPagination;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;

class AppNews extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;
    use WithFileUploads;

    public $filters = [
        'title' => '',
        'published' => '',
    ];
    ];
    public $uploaded_file_name;
    public $uploadedImageFilenameData;
    public $uploadedNewsImage;
    protected $listeners = ['fileUpload' => 'handleFileUpload'];


    public $current_news_id;
    public $updateMode = 'browse';

    public function render()
    {
        \Log::info('-1 NewsRENDER $this->filters ::' . print_r($this->filters, true));
        $news_rows_count  = News
            ::getByTitle($this->filters['title'], true)
            ->getByPublished($this->filters['published'], true)
            ->count();
        $backend_per_page = Settings::getValue('backend_per_page', CheckValueType::cvtInteger, 20);
        $this->emit('app_news_opened', ['mode' => 'browse', 'id' => null]);

        $newsPublishedValueArray = SetArrayHeader([['key' => '', 'label' => ' -Select published- ']], News::getNewsPublishedValueArray(true));
        $newsDataRows = News
            ::getByTitle($this->filters['title'], true)
            ->getByPublished($this->filters['published'], true)
            ->with('creator')
            ->orderBy('news.created_at', 'desc')
            ->paginate($backend_per_page);

        $newsDataIds = [];
        foreach ($newsDataRows as $nextNews) {
            $newsDataIds[] = $nextNews->id;
        }

        return view('livewire.admin.app-news.container', [
            'newsDataRows'             => $newsDataRows,
            'newsDataIds'              => $newsDataIds,
            'form'                     => $this->form,
            'news_rows_count'          => $news_rows_count,
            'newsPublishedValueArray'  => $newsPublishedValueArray,
        ]);
    }
```

and in the template resources/views/livewire/admin/app-news/container.blade.php :

```
<article class="admin_page_container">


<div class="card form-admin-news">
    
    <div class="card-body card-block">
    
        <div class="spinner-border" role="status" wire:loading>
            <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
        </div>
    
        ...
            <fieldset class="bordered text-muted p-2 m-2" x-data="{ title: '{{$filters['title']}}', published: '{{$filters['published']}}'  ,
                publishedItems: <?php print  str_replace('"',"'",json_encode( $newsPublishedValueArray) ) ?>   } ">
                <div> $filters::{{ var_dump($filters) }}</div>
                title::<div x-html="title"></div>
                published::<div x-html="published"></div>
                <legend class="bordered">Filters</legend>
                
                
                <dl class="block_2columns_md m-0 p-2">
                    <dt class="key_values_rows_label_13">
                        <label class="col-form-label" for="temp_filter_title">
                            By title
                        </label>
                    </dt>
                    <dd class="key_values_rows_value_13" >
                        <div class="content_with_right_button">
                            
                            <div
                                class="content_with_right_button_left_content"
                                wire:model.lazy="filters.title"
                            >
                                <input
                                    class="form-control admin_control_input"
                                    type="text"
                                    x-model="title"
                                    x-on:blur="$dispatch('input', title)"
                                    id="title"
                                >
                            </div>
                            <div class="content_with_right_button_right_button pl-2">
                                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary nowrap_block" wire:click="makeSearch( )">
                                    {!! $viewFuncs->showAppIcon('filter') !!}Search
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </dd>
                </dl>
                
                <dl class="block_2columns_md m-0 p-2">
                    <dt class="key_values_rows_label_13">
                        <label class="col-form-label" for="temp_filter_published">
                            By published
                        </label>
                    </dt>
                    <dd
                        class="key_values_rows_value_13"
                        wire:model.lazy="filters.published"
                    >
                        <select
                            x-model="published"
                            x-on:blur="$dispatch('select', published)"
                            id="published"
                            class="form-control editable_field admin_control_input"
                        >
                            <template x-for="nextPublishedItem in publishedItems">
                                <option :value="nextPublishedItem.key" x-text="nextPublishedItem.label"></option>
                            </template>
                        </select>
                        
                        @error('form.published')
                        <div class="validation_error">{{ clearValidationError($message,['form.'=>'']) }}</div> @enderror
                    </dd>
                </dl>
                
            </fieldset> <!-- Filters -->
        
        ...
        @endif {{-- @if($updateMode=='browse')--}}
        
    
        @endif {{-- @if($updateMode=='browse')--}}
            @if(count($newsDataRows) > 0)
                
                <div class="table-responsive table-wrapper-for-data-listing" x-data="selectedNewsIdsBoxXData()">
                    
                    <table>
                        ...
                    </table>
                </div> <!-- <div class="table-responsive table-wrapper-for-data-listing"> -->
            
            @endif {{-- @if(count($newsDataRows) > 0) --}}
        @endif {{-- @if($updateMode=='browse')  --}}
    </div> <!-- <div class="card-body card-block"> -->
    
    

</div> <!-- <div class="card"> -->
</article> <!-- page_content_container -->
```

Which is the valid way?

**Modified BLOCK 2:**

I try another way with using of alpinejs2 : I try to use it in this case, as when public var of component is changed:
with dispatch methid when button “Search” is clicked

```
<div class="card form-admin-facilities" x-data="adminFacilitiesComponent()">
    ...
    
    filter_name: {{$filter_name}}<br>
    ...
    temp_filter_name: <span x-html="temp_filter_name"></span><br>
    ...
    
    <fieldset class="bordered text-muted p-2 m-2">
        <legend class="bordered">Filters</legend>
        <div class="content_with_right_button" wire:model.lazy="filter_name">
            <div class="content_with_right_button_left_content" >
                <input
                    class="form-control admin_filter_input"
                    x-model="temp_filter_name"
                    
                    type="text"
                >
            </div>
            <div class="content_with_right_button_right_button pl-2" >
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" @click="$dispatch('input', temp_filter_name)"  type="button">Search
                </button>
                <!-- In more complicated form can be several filter fields : text and select inputs -->
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </fieldset> <!-- Filters -->
    
    
    ...
    <script>
        function adminFacilitiesComponent() {
            return {
                temp_filter_name:'',
```

and in the component I defined public $filter_name var, which is used in render method :

```
   class Facilities extends Component
        {
            public $form= [
                'name'=>'',
            'descr'=> '',
            'created_at'=> '',
            'is_reopen'       => false,
        ];

            public $current_facility_id;
            public $filter_name= '';
            public $updateMode = 'browse';

            public function render()
        {
        \Log::info( '-1 render Facilities $this->filter_name ::' . print_r(  $this->filter_name, true  ) );
            $this->facility_rows_count = Facility
                ::getByName($this->filter_name, true)
        ->count();
            $backend_per_page = Settings::getValue('backend_per_page', CheckValueType::cvtInteger, 20);

            return view('livewire.admin.facilities.container', [
                'facilityDataRows' => Facility
            ::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->getByName($this->filter_name, true)
        ->paginate($backend_per_page),
            'facility_rows_count'=> $this->facility_rows_count
        ]);
        }
```

But it does not work as I expect : entering value in text input when this input lose focus
form is rendered again. I expected form to be rendered only when I click on “Search” button
and form will be rendered with new entered value. I do not use blur event for text input and
do not understand why the form is rendered when this input lose focus?

**Modified BLOCK 3:**
Using x-ref= I do :

```
<div class="content_with_right_button" wire:model.lazy="filter_name">
    <div class="content_with_right_button_left_content" >
        <input
            class="form-control admin_filter_input"
            x-model="temp_filter_name"
            x-ref="searched"
            type="text"
        >       1111111
    </div>
    <div class="content_with_right_button_right_button pl-2" >
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary nowrap_block" wire:click="makeSearch(this.$refs.searched)" type="button">
            Search
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I got error clicking on search button:

```
VM1983:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'searched' of undefined
    at eval (eval at parseOutMethodAndParams (directive.js:55), <anonymous>:6:27)
    at _default.parseOutMethodAndParams (directive.js:55)
```

Looks like it is impossible to use this.$refs. value in

```
wire:click="makeSearch    .
```

I need to trigger component method

```
public function makeSearch($search_value='')
{
```

and send entered value into it.
Looks like the way I tried was invalid.
If there is a valid way?

Thanks!

Comment: Look at Modified BLOCK 2

Comment: I still search for a decision. How it can be implemented ? Who have similar issue : please share your expiernce.

Answer (score 2):

In your modified block 2, you should use `wire:ignore` in base div of your AlpineJS component. This will make livewire ignore the component.

```
<div class="card form-admin-facilities" wire:ignore x-data="adminFacilitiesComponent()">
```

Your `$dispatch()` should handle setting the value when you click the button.

Comment: Could you please give a link to docs where it is described ?

Comment: Yes,  wire:ignore  helped. Could you please explain what must be in $dispatch (on blur of the input ?) ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to make livewire ignore the component just add `wire:ignore` to your component's div in modified block 2 and then in your `dispatch` method you can write the logic that happens after clicking the button.

Comment: Could you please more details as for >>>in your dispatch method you can write the logic that happens after

Comment: @mstdmstd for example if you want the value of input on button click then you can assign `x-ref=searched` to the `input` element and gets it value is the  method via '`$refs.searched` or `this.$refs.searched` when clicking search button or whatever you like

Comment: Could you please take a look at Modified BLOCK 3